# PortAudio is not listing my USB audio card

Tags: usb, audio, c++

I'm having a weird issue currently, which I'm not too sure how to resolve as of right now.

On my Raspberry Pi 1, there's a USB sound card connected, where I need the microphone input from (the pi is connected via GPIO to a 64x64 RGB Matrix). Since the matrix driver needs snd_bcm2835 to be disabled, and I also need the mic input for sound visualization, I want to use the USB sound card together with PortAudio (and C++ using portaudiocpp).

I use this code for initializing and enumerating the audio devices on the Pi:

```
void CAudio::Initialize()
{
    PaError err = Pa_Initialize();
    if (err != paNoError)
    {
        CLogging::Log(LogAudio, Error, "Couldn't initialize audio interface! Error: %s", Pa_GetErrorText(err));
        return;
    }

    const PaDeviceInfo* deviceInfo;
    int num = Pa_GetDeviceCount();
    CLogging::Log(LogAudio, Message, "Num %d", num);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        deviceInfo = Pa_GetDeviceInfo(i);

        CLogging::Log(LogAudio, Message, "Device %s", deviceInfo->name);
    }

    Initialized = true;
}
```

But unfortunately it's only logging "Num 0", so it doesn't enumerate my USB sound card. Output from `aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Device [USB PnP Sound Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

What's happening here? Thanks in advance!